# how to project data change into child component with angular2?

Tags: promise, angular

i'm trying to build angular2 component which draws chart (using jquery plot)

```
import {Component, ElementRef, Input, OnChanges} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'flot',
  template: `<div>loading</div>`
})

export class FlotCmp  implements OnChanges{

  private width = '100%';
  private height = 220;
  static chosenInitialized = false;

  @Input() private  options: any;
  @Input() private  dataset:any;
  @Input() private  width:string;
  @Input() private  height:string;


  constructor(public el: ElementRef) {}



  ngOnChanges() {
      if(!FlotCmp.chosenInitialized) {
        let plotArea = $(this.el.nativeElement).find('div').empty();
        plotArea.css({
            width: this.width, 
            height: this.height
        });

        $.plot( plotArea, this.dataset, this.options);    
        FlotCmp.chosenInitialized = true;
      }
  } 
}
```

Component getting chart "data" property as input parameter:

```
      <flot  [options]="splineOptions" [dataset]="dataset" height="250px" width="100%"></flot>
```

So far i managed to make it work as long as "dataset" is static variable.

```
 this.dataset = [{label: "line1",color:"blue",data:[[1, 130], [3, 80], [4, 160], [5, 159], [12, 350]]}];
```

My problem is to make it work when data came as a promise:

```
export class App implements OnInit {

  private dataset:any;
  public entries;  
  getEntries() {
    this._flotService.getFlotEntries().then(
                       entries => this.dataset[0].data = entries,
                       error =>  this.errorMessage = <any>error);
  } 

  ngOnInit() {  
    this.getEntries() 
  } 



  constructor(private _flotService:FlotService) {
    this.name = 'Angular2'
    this.splineOptions = {
            series: {
                lines: { show: true },
                points: {
                    radius: 3,
                    show: true
                }
            }
    };
    this.dataset = [{label: "line1",color:"blue",data:null]}];

  }

}
```

For some reason data change cannot project to "flot" component

here is link to [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/n7Y5o6i1DL60wCfkYbBc?p=preview)

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides Günter's answer, another option is to implement your own change detection inside `ngDoCheck()` which will be called when your data comes back from the server:

```
ngDoCheck() {
   if(this.dataset[0].data !== null && !this.dataPlotted) {
      console.log('plotting data');
      let plotArea = $(this.el.nativeElement).find('div').empty();
      $.plot( plotArea, this.dataset, this.options);    
      this.dataPlotted = true;
   }
}
```

I feel this is a cleaner approach, since we don't have to write code a specific way just to satisfy/trigger Angular change detection.  But alas, it is less efficient.  (I hate it when that happens!)

Also, the code you have in `ngOnChanges()` can be moved to `ngOnInit()`.

<kbd>[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/HaQ0VHsPr3DnnFmND3BE?p=preview)</kbd>

As Günter already mentioned, `ngOnChanges()` isn't called because the `dataset` array reference doesn't change when you fill in your data.  So Angular doesn't think any input properties changed, so `ngOnChanges()` isn't called.  `ngDoCheck()` is always called every change detection cycle, whether or not there are any input property changes.

---

Yet another option is to use `@ViewChild(FlotCmp)` in the parent component, which will get a reference to `FlotCmp`.  The parent could then use that reference to call some method, say `drawPlot()`, on `FlotCmp` to draw/update the plot when the data arrives.

```
drawPlot(dataset) {
  console.log('plotting data', dataset);
  let plotArea = $(this.el.nativeElement).find('div').empty();
  $.plot( plotArea, dataset, this.options);
  this.dataset = dataset;
}
```

<kbd>[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/7qkMEd4048hS9St1AKdf?p=preview)</kbd>

This is more efficient than `ngDoCheck()`, and it doesn't have the issue I described above with the `ngOnChanges()` approach.

However, if I were to use this approach, I would rework the code somewhat, since I don't like how `dataset` is currently an input property, but then `drawPlot()` gets the data passed in via a function argument.

Comment: Thank you very much for this very detailed very clear explanation

Answer (score 2):

The problem is

```
entries => this.dataset[0].data = entries,
```

because only the inner state of the bound value is changed and Angular2 change detection doesn't observe the content only the value or reference itself.

A workaround would be to create a new array with the same content

```
this._flotService.getFlotEntries().then(
                   entries => {
                     this.dataset[0].data = entries;
                     this.dataset = this.dataset.slice();
                   },
```

In your case an additional event could work that notifies the child component that updates have happended.